# Visual studio code - change stateless widget into stateful

Tags: visual-studio-code

I am switching IDE from Atom to Visual Studio Code for Flutter and have become totally stuck with the following:

> You can just place your cursor on the StatelessWidget, press Alt +
>   Enter and click on Convert to StatefulWidget. All the boilerplate
>   code will be created for you, automatically.

No matter what I try I cannot get the option to convert to appear, I assume I am missing an extension but at a total loss and going round in circles.

Answer (score 3):

After a lot of trial and error, I stumbled across the correct key code.
It works with the following two keys: Ctrl and full stop (IE: <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>.</kbd>).